# How to align my dropdown menu to center of the page?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, alignment

So if you want to see my menu go [here](http://www.gameplay-universe.uphero.com/).

Since I know you'll want my source, here's the HTML:

```
<div id='menu-container'>
<ul id='menu' class="menu">
   <li class='active'><a href='/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='/games/'><span>Games</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='/games/dota-2/'><span>Dota 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/games/cs-go/'><span>CS: GO</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/games/css/'><span>CS: Source</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/games/terraria/'><span>Terraria</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='/games/minecraft/'><span>Minecraft</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='/about.html'><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul> 
         <li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/'><span>Our YouTube Channel</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/faq-list.html'><span>Our FAQs/Q&amp;A List</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/feed-news.rss'><span>Our RSS Feed</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/wiki/'><span>Our Wiki</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='/wiki/'><span>Our Blog</span></a></li>
                 <li class='last'><a href='/privacy.html'><span>Privacy Policy</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub last'><a href='/contact.html'><span>Contact Us</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='/forums/'><span>Forums</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
}
#menu-container ul,
#menu-container li,
#menu-container span,
#menu-container a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#menu-container {
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
}
#menu-container:after,
#menu-container ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#menu-container a {
  background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-container ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-container > ul {
  float: left;
}
#menu-container > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
}
#menu-container > ul > li.active > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#menu-container > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}
#menu-container .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#menu-container .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6fc7ec;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6db2d0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #095c80;
}
#menu-container {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
```

It's much, but if I don't give it you'll report me so how to align the menu to the center of my page (since I didn't code this, it was my friend)? And I also want the menu only, without the empty grey space. Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds more like "Can you do this for me?" rather than "How can I do this?"

Comment: Yes, an easy way would be to give `#menu-container` a `width: 346px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` (assuming you have access and know how to code CSS). @SimonArnold Isn't that essentially the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMVpn/1/) that shows you how to align your menu to the center of the screen. You can search for my changes in the css by searching for "EDITED". I marked all 3 changes that way.

Here is what I did.

1.Remove the rule that makes the whole menu float left :

```
#menu-container > ul {
    float: left;
}
```

2.Specify on his parent element that you want it in the center of the page :

```
#menu-container {text-align:center;}
```

3.Then for each menu element, change the following rule :

```
#menu-container > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
#menu-container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As for your last question (I also want the menu only, without the empty grey space), I don't understand what you mean. You want to remove the grey color from the menu bar?